# Detect redux store changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I want to save data of every reducer in localStorage in the form of key value pairs

1. `UserReducer: {isLoding: true, ....}`
2. `OrderReducer : {isRecieved: false, ....}`

So if there is any changes happen in any of the reducer I want to set the updated data in local storage.
What I am thinking is I can do this store.subscribe but how I could know that which reducer has been changed so I can set the whole reducer data to localStorage.
Need help. Thanks :)

Comment: you could use redux-persist

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to create a `lastAction` reducer which will store the value of the last dispatched action. Then in store.subscribe you could do:

```
    let nextState = store.getState();
    let dispatchedAction = nextState.lastAction.type;
```

And when you know the last dispatched action, you can update the local storage depending on that action type.

Comment: I do not find the lastAction in Redux documentation.

Comment: lastAction is just a normal reducer which will store the value of the dispatched action. You can name it whatever you want :)

Comment: I see now. It is a creative way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `redux` middleware, it will get fired everytime an action is dispatched. Within the middleware you can put a conditional check to see if prev and next store are same. If not, you can update your local storage.

I found [this](https://medium.com/netscape/creating-custom-middleware-in-react-redux-961570459ecb) helpful for creating a middleware. And it's fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could not know the changes from the store.subscribe.

The last place when you know the changes are the actions.

1. You can put the persisting logic to the reducers. But maybe you should not want to introduce side effect in your reducer.

So basically you have two options if you rule out the first one.

2. Persist the whole store as a single object to local storage. It is the easier option. I would try this solution first and I would measure the overhead with a worst case scenario.
3. Make a redux middleware and capture the individual actions. You can copy the reducer pattern to persist only the object that changed.

You can use subscribe for option 2. You can use middleware for option 2 and option 3.

I came up with one more solution.

4. You can do the persisting in your action creator with Redux Thunk or with Redux Saga.

Answer (score 1):

You can use React Component for that. Connect it to the Store, and use it to write to localStorage instead of rendering something. 
Imho, it would be easier to write than middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [redux-watch](https://github.com/jprichardson/redux-watch) to listen to the changes in redux store

for e.g.

```
// ... other imports/requires
import watch from 'redux-watch'

// assuming you have an admin reducer / state slice
console.log(store.getState().admin.name) // 'JP'

// store is THE redux store
let w = watch(store.getState, 'admin.name')
store.subscribe(w((newVal, oldVal, objectPath) => {
  console.log('%s changed from %s to %s', objectPath, oldVal, newVal)
  // admin.name changed from JP to JOE
}))

// somewhere else, admin reducer handles ADMIN_UPDATE
store.dispatch({ type: 'ADMIN_UPDATE', payload: { name: 'JOE' }})
```

this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I want to extend the approach 3 that @PeterAmbruzs shared. Actually the problem which I faced was whenever there was an action dispatched, store wasn't updated immediately but I still wanted to persist it so I imported reducer and passed state and action into it to get the required next state

```
import reducer from './reducer'

const someMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    const state = store.getState(),
    const nextState = reducer(state, action)
    
    // Save it to Local Storage
    // Or Make an API Call to save it to server        

    next(action)
}
```